# How to prove these using natural deduction

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I'd like to prove the following logical equivalence by using natural deduction:
$$(\exists x)(p(x) \implies q) \dashv\vdash (\forall x)(p(x)) \implies q.$$

As far as I'm concerned to show that two statements are equivalent we should show proofs for both of the sides. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @BlediBoss Can you do either direction?

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I did the opposite direction of the given logical equivalence.

Comment: You need to adapt this to whatever inference rules you have: suppose $(\exists x)(p(x) \implies q) $ is true. Then there exists a constant $a$ such that $p(a)\to q$. (You want to prove that  $(\forall x)(p(x)) \to q$, so) assume $(\forall x)(p(x))$ is true. Then it is true in particular for $a$, that is, $p(a)$ is true. From here it's easy to conclude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first direction, $(\exists x)(p(x)\implies q) \vdash (\forall x)(p(x))\implies q$, we could reason as follows (in a natural deduction system):

1. $(\exists x)(p(x)\implies q)\quad {\sf P}\quad$ 1
2. $p(a)\implies q \quad {\sf EI(1)}\quad$ 1
3. $(\forall x)(p(x))\quad{\sf P}\quad$ 3
4. $p(a)\quad {\sf UI(3)}\quad$ 3
5. $q \quad {\sf MP(2,4)}\quad$ 1,3
6. $(\forall x)(p(x))\implies q\quad {\sf CondI(3,5)}\quad$ 1

For the converse (which you state to have proven already -- this is just for completeness' sake), we could do:

1. $(\forall x)(p(x)) \lor \neg (\forall x)(p(x))\quad {\sf LEM}\quad$
2. $(\forall x)(p(x)) \implies q\quad{\sf P}\quad$ 2
3. $(\forall x)(p(x))\quad{\sf P}\quad$ 3
4. $q\quad\sf MP(2,3)\quad$ 2,3
5. $p(a)\quad\sf P\quad$ 5
6. $p(a)\implies q\quad\sf CondI(5,4)\quad$ 2,3
7. $(\exists x)(p(x)\implies q)\quad\sf EG(6)\quad$ 2,3
8. $(\forall x)(p(x)) \implies (\exists x)(p(x)\implies q)\quad \sf CondI(3,7)\quad$ 2
9. $\neg(\forall x)(p(x))\quad\sf P\quad$ 9
10. $(\exists x)(\neg p(x))\quad\sf TI(9)\quad$ 9
11. $\neg p(a)\quad\sf EI(10)\quad$ 9
12. $p(a)\quad\sf P\quad$ 12
13. $\bot\quad\sf BI(11,12)\quad$ 9,12
14. $q\quad\sf BE(13)\quad$ 9,12
15. $p(a)\implies q\quad\sf CondI(12,14)\quad$ 9
16. $(\exists x)(p(x)\implies q)\quad\sf EG(15)\quad$ 9
17. $\neg(\forall x)(p(x))\implies (\exists x)(p(x)\implies q)\quad\sf CondI(9,16)$
18. $(\exists x)(p(x)\implies q)\quad \sf DisjE(1,8,17)\quad$ 2

Where at line 10, the (somewhat tedious to prove) equivalence between $\neg(\forall x)(p(x))$ and $(\exists x)(\neg p(x))$ was used to keep the proof reasonably short.

The abbreviations used for the respective rules should be easily readable to anyone familiar with natural deduction. If someone would appreciate them being explained explicitly, please let me know in the comments.

The lines in above derivations follow the scheme:

> Line number. Formula$\quad$Rule$\quad$Undischarged premises

---

**Added:** It is worthwhile to note that the invocation of the Law of Excluded Middle is used essentially in the second proof. The two propositions are inequivalent in intuitionistic logic (the logic which accepts everything from classical logic except LEM (and its sister DNE, $\neg\neg p \vdash p$)).

We also have proven the [drinker paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox) as a special case (with $q = (\forall x)(p(x))$). It's fun to read about.

Answer (score 1):

Just for practice, here's another Fitch style proof, using proof by contradiction (DNE rather than LEM) and only fundamental rules of induction.$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}{\fitch{~~1.~\exists x~(p(x)\to q)\hspace{16ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~2.~\forall x~p(x)\hspace{19ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{~~3.~[c]~p(c)\to q\hspace{11.5ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{~~4.~p(c)\hspace{19ex}{\forall}\textsf{Elimination 2}\\~~5.~ q\hspace{22ex}{\to}\textsf{Elimination 4,3}}\\~~6.~q\hspace{25ex}\exists\textsf{Elimination 1,3-5}}\\~~7.~(\forall x~p(x))\to q\hspace{16ex}{\to}\textsf{Introduction 2-6}}\\\exists x~(p(x)\to q)~\vdash~(\forall x~p(x))\to q\\~\\\fitch{~~8.~(\forall x~p(x))\to q\hspace{17ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~9.~\neg\exists x~(p(x)\to q)\hspace{12ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{10.~\exists x~\neg p(x)\hspace{15ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{11.~[c]~\neg p(c)\hspace{12.5ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{12.~p(c)\hspace{13.5ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{13.~\bot\hspace{16ex}\neg\textsf{Elimination}\\14.~q\hspace{16.5ex}\textsf{Ex Falso Quodlibet}}\\15.~p(c)\to q\hspace{12ex}{\to}\textsf{Introduction}\\16.~\exists x~(p(x)\to q)\hspace{7ex}\exists\textsf{Introduction 15}\\17.~\bot\hspace{19ex}\neg\textsf{Elimination 16,9}}\\18.~\bot\hspace{22ex}\exists\textsf{Elimination 10,11-17}}\\19.~\neg\exists x~\neg p(x)\hspace{17ex}\neg\textsf{Introduction 10-18}\\\fitch{20.~[a]\hspace{22ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{21.~\neg p(a)\hspace{15.5ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{22.~\exists x~\neg p(x)\hspace{12ex}\exists\textsf{Introduction 21}\\23.~\bot\hspace{19ex}\neg\textsf{Elimination 22,19}}\\22.~\neg\neg p(a)\hspace{17ex}\neg\textsf{Introduction 21-23}\\23.~p(a)\hspace{20ex}\neg\neg\textsf{Elimination 22}}\\24.~\forall x~p(x)\hspace{20ex}\forall\textsf{Introduction 20-23}\\25.~q\hspace{26.5ex}{\to}\textsf{Elimination 24,8}\\26.~\exists x~q\hspace{23ex}\exists\textsf{Introduction 25}\\\fitch{27.~[c]~q\hspace{20ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{28.~p(c)\hspace{17ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{29.~q\hspace{20ex}\textsf{Reiteration 27}}\\30.~p(c)\to q\hspace{16ex}{\to}\textsf{Introduction 28-29}\\31.~\exists x~(p(c)\to q)\hspace{11ex}\exists\textsf{Introduction 30}\\32.~\bot\hspace{23ex}\neg\textsf{Elimination 31,9}}\\33.~\bot\hspace{26ex}\exists\textsf{Elimination 26,27-32}}\\34.~\neg\neg\exists x~(p(x)\to q)\hspace{14ex}{\neg}\textsf{Introduction 9-33}\\35.~\exists x~(p(x)\to q)\hspace{17ex}{\neg\neg}\textsf{Elimination 34}}\\(\forall x~p(x))\to q~\vdash~ \exists x~(p(x)\to q)}$$

Answer (score -1):

Here is a similar proof using a Fitch-style proof checker:

[image]

On line 9, rather than taking the negation of the goal, I tool the negation of the [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) equivalence of the goal.  It was (perhaps) easier to reach a contradiction using that technique. Regardless, from that result on line 14, I still had to derive the desired goal.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/